# проблемма с users.get vk.api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, requests, vk-mini-apps

Я использую метод users.get для получения информации с профиля пользователя вк. Возьмем случайную страницу https://vk.com/id680277389 . При запросе вида vk_api.users.get(user_id=vk_Id, v=5.131), получаю следующий ответ: [{'id': 680277389, 'first_name': 'Viktoria', 'last_name': 'Ubogova', 'can_access_closed': True, 'is_closed': False}]. Однако тут не отображаются школа и город указанные пользователем. Подскажите, что я делаю не так, при получении информации с профиля таким образом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты не передаешь список дополнительных полей "fields", которые нужно вернуть! Почитай внимательно документацию. https://dev.vk.com/method/users.get

К примеру, чтобы получить поле "bdate" в запросе его нужно передать, чтобы оно было включено в ответ:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&access_token=533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ac114461ae8736d6506a3&v=5.131
```

Ответ такой:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 210700286,
      "first_name": "Lindsey",
      "last_name": "Stirling",
      "bdate": "21.9.1986"
    }
  ]
}
```